# Может ли работать QT Charts и QTableView на Raspberry Pi 3+?

Tags: qt5, raspberry-pi, arm, raspbian

На Raspberry PI 3+ OS Raspbian установлена последняя версия Qt5, компилятор gcc и g++ подключены, настройки сделаны. Простые проекты работают. Но рабочий проект перенесенный с Windows в котором есть Qt Charts и QTableView не компилируется. Проблема в строчках файла проекта

```
requires(qtConfig(tableview))
```

и

```
QT += CHARTS
```

Провел эксперимент в Ubuntu на x86 там проблема только с

```
QT += CHARTS
```

Правильно ли я понял, что Qt Charts существует только в коммерческой версии Qt под Linux? Существует ли Qt Charts в коммерческой версии Qt под ARM? Какие библиотеки для графиков работают на Raspberry PI?

Работают ли QTableView в Linux для ARM и как их добавить?

Comment: Попробовал сам собрать Qt Charts из исходников
https://github.com/qt/qtcharts

получил ошибку

error: missing binary operator before token "("
#if QT_CONFIG(tooltip)

С таблицами похоже проблема с qtConfig, Qt не знает такой функции для файла проекта. Qt установлено из репозиториев Raspberry версии Qt 5.7.1

Answer (score 1):

Итог, про QtCharts пришлось забыть, как его откомпелировать под 32х разрядную систему под ARM не понятно. Под 32х разрядный x86 тоже. Для 32х разрядных систем сборки Qt существуют только старых версий.

На 64х разрядном процессоре amd64 в Linux64 все работает из коробки, как и под Windows64, если устанавливать бесплатную версию установщиком с сайта Qt, а не из репозиториев.

64х разрядные версии Linux под Raspi не работают, мало памяти (запускаются, но чуть, что виснут), так что проверить работают ли QtCharts в Linux64 под ARM пока не удается.

Попробывал графические библиотеки QCustomPlot и Qwt, перешел на Qwt.

Таблицы работают, старые версии Qt5 не знают макроса

```
requires(qtConfig(tableview))
```

Также пришлось подправить код под более старые компиляторы, но С++11 в целом работает

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемый автор,qtcharts существует в git и доступен для некоммерческого использования. Ниже привожу инструкцию как qtcharts получить:

При сборке Qt из git нужно указать, что требуется также модуль qtcharts, а мусор не требуется. (Дано: папка qt5 - с исходниками с git, папка build - из неё конфигурируем и билдим, build_artifacts - папка для мусора от сборки, все три папки в одном каталоге) git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git qt5 && cd qt5 && perl init-repository --module-subset=default,qtcharts,-qtwebengine,-qtwayland,-qtandroidextras,-qtvirtualkeyboard,-qtquick3d && cd ../build Затем нужно сконфигурировать (без мусора): ../qt5/configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests -confirm-license -skip webengine -skip qtwayland -skip qtandroidextras -skip qtdoc -skip qtgraphicaleffects -skip qtqa -skip qttranslations -skip qtvirtualkeyboard -skip qtquicktimeline -skip qtquick3d -skip qtrepotools -skip qtdeclarative -skip qttools -skip qtshadertools -skip qtimageformats -skip qtnetworkauth -skip qtquickcontrols2 -skip qtsvg -skip qtwebsockets -skip qt5compat -opengl es2 -prefix ../build_artifacts -v Очевидно, моя машинка не поддерживает Desktop OpenGL. Однако при сборке make -j8 в модуле qtcharts ругается fatal error: QtWidgets/QOpenGLWidget: No such file or directory. Как переключить qtcharts на использование OpenGL ES2 мне [неведомо](https://forum.qt.io/topic/115816/build-qtcharts-with-opengl-es2), однако на десктопах проблем не должно возникнуть.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите сообщение в порядок. Оредактировать можно кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1140242/edit). В окне правки на панели вверху, найдёте различные инструменты и помошь к ним.